# getRowHeight() in java method

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I dont understand how to implement this method in my table class

```
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;

public class Tabel extends AbstractTableModel{
    Object columnNames[];
    Object rowData[][];
    public Tabel(Object[][] rowData2, Object[] columnNames2) {
        rowData=rowData2; 
        columnNames=columnNames2;

    }


@Override
public int getColumnCount() {
    return columnNames.length;
}
public int getRowCount() {
    return rowData.length;
}

@Override
public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
    return rowData[rowIndex][columnIndex];
} 
public void SetValoare(Object value,int row ,int col) { 
    rowData[row][col]=value;
    fireTableCellUpdated(row,col); 

} 
public int getRowHeight() { 

}

public void ChangeHeight(int row,int column) { 
    int i=rowData.length;       
}
 }
```

I don't now what to return because if I write something like this return `rowData.height;`  doesn't work i need this to make a method that changes the height of a specific row and column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't implement getRowHeight() in the TableModel. The TableModel only stores the data and does not know how the data will be rendered.

> i need this to make a method that changes the heigth of a specific row

If you want to change the height of a specific row then you can use the method from JTable:

```
table.setRowHeight(row, height);
```

> and column

You can't change the height of a specific column. The height of all columns for a given row will be the same.

Comment: I want to chenge the height of a specific cell sorry  that is why i want to make a method and how can i overwrite this method ?

Comment: I just stated that you can't change the height of a specific cell! The JTable is designed to be displayed in a row/column grid. You would need to completely rewrite the UI of the JTable which is far above my skill level.